# Graphics and Objects

Tags: java, object, graphics

okay so my question is why am I getting no values for the points that Im trying to use to draw my rectangle. Ive been trying to figure it out but I just cant seem to get it. Could someone please take a look at my code and let me know what Im doing wrong. Thank you so much to whoever can figure it out

My Square class:

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Color;
 import javax.swing.JPanel;


import java.util.Random;
import java.awt.*;


class Square{

    int x1, y1, x3, y3;

    int red, green, blue;


    Square (){};

    public double squareArea()
    {

        return Math.abs(x3 - x1) * Math.abs(y3 - y1);
    }

    public void setUpperLeft (int ulx, int uly)
    {
        x1 = ulx;
        y1 = uly;
    }

    public void setLowRight (int lrx, int lry)
    {
        x3 = lrx;
        y3 = lry;
    }

    void setRed(int c){red = c;}

    void setGreen (int c) {green = c;}

    void setBlue (int c){blue = c;}

    void setSquareData(int x1, int y1, int x3, int y3, int red, int green, int blue)
    {
        Random r = new Random();
        Dimension screenSize=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            x1 = r.nextInt(screenSize.width);
            y1 = r.nextInt(screenSize.height);
            //s[i].setUpperLeft(x, y);

            x3 = r.nextInt(screenSize.width);
            y3 = r.nextInt(screenSize.height);
            //s[i*2].setLowRight(x2, y2);

            red = r.nextInt(255) * 2;
            green = r.nextInt(255) * 2;
            blue = r.nextInt(255) * 3;


        }
    }

    int getRed(){ return red;}

    int getGreen () {return green;}

    int getBlue (){return blue;}


    int getx1()
    {
        return x1; 
    }

    int gety1()
    {
        return y1;
    }

    int getx3()
    {
        return x3; 
    }

    int gety3()
    {
        return y3;
    }


}
```

My Draw Class

```
 import java.util.Random;
 import java.awt.*; 
import java.awt.Graphics; 
import java.awt.Color; 
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Draw extends JPanel { 
> 
>       public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {            
        Color c;
>       int red, green, blue;           
        int x1, y1, x2, y2;
> 
>     Dimension screenSize =Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();      
>           
>                       int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
>                       int screenWidth = screenSize.width;
> 
>               Square s = new Square();
>           
>               Random r = new Random();
> 
>               for( int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
>               {
>               Square[] sq = new Square[100];
> 
>               x1 = s.getx1();
>                                 y1 = s.gety1();
>                                 x2 = s.getx3();
>                                 y2 = s.gety3();
>  
>                                 red = s.getRed();
>                                 green = s.getGreen();
>                                 blue = s.getBlue();
>  
>                                 c = new Color(s.getRed(), s.getGreen(), s.getBlue());
>                                 g.setColor(c);
>                                 g.drawLine(x1,y1,x2,y2);
>  
>                                 g.fillRect(x1, y1, x2, y2);
>               
>               
>               
>               }
> 
> 
> 
> 
>       }
> 
> }
```

My main Class

```
 import javax.swing.JFrame;
 import java.awt.*;
 class Main{

 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
    Square s = new Square();
            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Squares");
            Draw myDraw = new Draw();
            Dimension screenSize =           Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();

            int screenHeight = screenSize.height;
            int screenWidth = screenSize.width;

            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setSize(screenWidth, screenHeight);
            frame.getContentPane().add(myDraw);
            frame.setVisible(true);

    System.out.printf("Poop: %d", s.getx1() ); // was testing the values
```

}
}

Comment: You may want to be more precise in your question, well, or at least, make a question.

Comment: Why isnt it drawing anything and why do my values have no values in them

Comment: they have no values in them because you have never set any value in them.

Comment: I set them in the Square class or at least I think I did

Comment: I don't see any calls to any of the methods that would set a size or color for any of the Squares you create.

Comment: Also, you need to be creating the GUI parts on the EventDispatchThread, not the main thread.

Comment: Why do you have all those input variables to setSquareData() when you just ignore them, set them to new values, and then throw away the new values? Note that the argument names hide similar instance names. Also, you never call setSquareData().

Answer (score 1):

Your paintComponent() method creates a new Square (called "s"), which has zero size. then you create 10,000 more Squares of zero size and try to draw the original square (with zero size) 100 times.

You shouldn't be creating ANY Square instances in the paintComponent() method. As you have written it, whenever the user resizes the frame, you will end up creating millions of Squares, which are immediately discarded when the method returns. 
So here's an example that draws rectangles:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Draw extends JPanel {

   JFrame          frame;
   ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();
   static Random   r     = new Random();

   public Draw() {
      setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 300 ) );
   }

   public void addItem( Item s ) {
      items.add( s );
      repaint();
   }

   /**
    * Adds a Item of random size and color.
    */
   public void addItem() {
      int w = getWidth();
      int h = getHeight();

      int sx = r.nextInt( w );
      int sw = sx + r.nextInt( w - sx );

      int sy = r.nextInt( h );
      int sh = sy + r.nextInt( h - sy );
      int red = r.nextInt( 255 );
      int green = r.nextInt( 255 );
      int blue = r.nextInt( 255 );
      Color c = new Color( red, green, blue );
      Item s = new Item( sx, sy, sw, sh, c );
      addItem( s );
   }

   @Override
   public void paintComponent( Graphics g ) {
      super.paintComponent( g );
      for (Item s : items) {
         g.setColor( s.c );
         g.fillRect( s.x, s.y, s.width, s.height );
      };
   }

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable() {
         @Override
         public void run() {
            JFrame jf = new JFrame();
            jf.getContentPane().setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
            jf.addWindowListener( new WindowAdapter() {
               @Override
               public void windowClosing( WindowEvent arg0 ) {
                  System.exit( 0 );
               }
            } );
            Draw t = new Draw();
            jf.add( t );
            jf.pack();
            jf.setVisible( true );

            // Now add some rectangles

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
               t.addItem();
            }
         }
      } );
   }

   class Item {
      int   x;
      int   y;
      int   width;
      int   height;
      Color c;

      public Item( int x1, int y1, int w, int h, Color c ) {
         x = x1;
         y = y1;
         width = w;
         height = h;
         this.c = c;
      }
   }
}
```